# Error running timer: (error "Candidates function `helm-git-grep-process' should run a process")

Tags: helm, helm-grep

I'm getting this error when trying to run helm-git-grep. As soon as I start typing the first character of the pattern, I get this:

```
Error running timer: (error "Candidates function `helm-git-grep-process' should run a process")
```

Comment: Show your code or provide a step-by-step recipe, starting from `emacs -Q` (no init file). If you don't get the error without your init file then consider reporting the problem to the Helm maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

It works if I have a file open that is part of a git repository.

If I open a file that isn't part of a git repository then I get that error.